# Differences between queryset_iterator and Django Paginator

Tags: python, django

I'm having a discussion with a coworker about iterating through large tables via the Django ORM. Up to now I've been using an implementation of a [queryset_iterator](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1949/) as seen here:

```
def queryset_iterator(queryset, chunksize=1000):
    '''''
    Iterate over a Django Queryset ordered by the primary key

    This method loads a maximum of chunksize (default: 1000) rows in it's
    memory at the same time while django normally would load all rows in it's
    memory. Using the iterator() method only causes it to not preload all the
    classes.

    Note that the implementation of the iterator does not support ordered query sets.
    '''
    pk = 0
    last_pk = queryset.order_by('-pk')[0].pk
    queryset = queryset.order_by('pk')
    while pk < last_pk:
        for row in queryset.filter(pk__gt=pk)[:chunksize]:
            pk = row.pk
            yield row
        gc.collect()
```

My coworker suggested using [Django's Paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/pagination/) and passing the queryset into that. It seems like similar work would done, and the only difference I can find is that the Paginator doesn't make any garbage collecting calls.

Can anybody shed light on the difference between the two? Is there any?

Answer (score 3):

The implementation here is totally different to what Paginator does; there are almost no similarities at all.

Your class iterates through an entire queryset, requesting `chunksize` items at a time, each chunk being a separate query. It can only be used on non-ordered queries because it does its own order_by call.

Paginator does nothing like this. It is not for iterating over an entire queryset, but for returning a single page from the full qs, which it does with a single query using the slice operators (which map to LIMIT/OFFSET).

Separately, I'm not sure what you think calling `gc.collect` would do here. The garbage collector is an add-on to the main memory management system, which is reference counting. It is only useful in cleaning up circular references, and there is no reason to believe any would be created here.